# click a button on a second html page automatically when directed one html page

Tags: javascript, html, django

How can I make a button (a form button) to be auto clicked when we click a button on one webpage "abc/x" where x is an id and hence is a variable.

So "abc/123","abc/234" etc are webpages having a "button1". So when we click button1- we should be directed to url "abc/pqr" and a "button2" should be auto-clicked. This button should only be clicked when directed from abc/x and not when from any other url. Any pointers how to proceed?

Comment: To my knowledge, JS doesn't do well with passing knowledge from one page to another.  I'd suggest either logging the info in a cookie (and reading it on the new page) or passing in extra values through the URL and on the second page running code to parse the URL information.

Comment: I've also seen developers flatten out their sites to be single page web apps so that they can persist knowledge this way. Although, I don't know how well this concept would work for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically button clicked, use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
  document.getElementById('clickButton').click();
}

function doyouraction()
{
   // your action
}
</script>

<input onclick="doyouraction()" type="button" id="clickButton" value="Button">
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can call the function which is called on button click from window.onload function.

Or

You can perform the button click like this:
document.getElementById(BTN_ID).click():